# Помогите с установкой эмулятора на Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Emulator: PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android\Android_SDK]!
Уже не знаю что и делать, переустанавливал, папку adv переносил.
Знаю, что скорее всего проблема из-за учётной записи(У меня она на кириллице).
Помогите пожалуйста [image: brabusmaxz]

Comment: Учетная запись не причем, ошибка в android sdk, попробуйте его переустановить/перекачать

Comment: Переустанавливал уже около 7 раз.Менял папки всё без толку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value - некоторое решение, так же, рекомендую использовать Genymotion или реальное устройство, а то в AS вечные ошибки то не нахождения, то не совместимости

Answer (score -1):

Я установил Genimotion, всё работает.